# How to make below style:

Tags: css, html

I'd like to achieve something like this:

[image]

I've done this so far:

[image]

just wondering, how to make a purple area with little arrow button and once user click it, it would invoke something.

Here is the html and css code I have:

```
  <div class="searchy">
    <input type="search" name="ttsearch" data-style="mini" data-theme="d" placeholder="Search here..." class="fdSearch" value=""/> 
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
 .searchy{

 height: 60px;
 background-color: #555;
 color: #FFF;
 margin-left: -15px;
 margin-right: -15px;
 }

 .fdSearch{

 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 5px solid #E5E4E2;
 margin: 2px;
 margin-left: -15px;
 margin-right: -15px;
 height: 40px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding: 20px;
margin-top: 15px;
width: 85%;


}
```

===================update==========================

Thank you guys....They all works. I just pick up one for the right answer.
I've learnt a lot from codes with different version of answers below. Thank you for your help again.

Comment: You could build the purple box as a separate div within the input box, and then set it to display:none. And then use CSS transitions so when input:focus you make it display:block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hBdMz/

Css:

```
.form-wrapper {
    width: auto;
    padding:4px;
    background: #555;
    clear:both;
    display:table;
}

/* Form text input */

.form-wrapper input {
    width: 330px;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px 5px;
    float: left;    
    border: 0;
    background: white;
    border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px; 
    outline:none;
}


/* Form submit button */
.form-wrapper button {
    overflow: visible;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border: 0;
    padding: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
    height: 40px;
    width: 110px;
    color: black;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    background: #9B30FF;
    border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;      
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0 ,0, .3);
}   



.form-wrapper button:before { 
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-width: 8px 8px 8px 0;
    border-style: solid solid solid none;
    border-color: transparent #9B30FF transparent;
    top: 12px;
    left: -6px;
}
```

Html:

```
 <div class="form-wrapper">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search here..." required>
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
```

Adapted from: [speckyboy](http://speckyboy.com/2012/02/15/how-to-build-a-stylish-css3-search-box/)

Answer (score 2):

Check This **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wVJWy/2/)**

HTML

```
<div class="searchy">
    <input type="search" name="ttsearch" data-style="mini" data-theme="d" placeholder="Search here..." class="fdSearch"
    value=""/> 
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>  
</div>
```

CSS

```
.searchy {
    background: grey;
    padding: 50px 20px;
}
input {
    border:none;
    background: none;
    border-top: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-left: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
    padding: 10px 3px;
}

button {

    border:none;
    background: #4fd577;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    border-top: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-right: 3px solid #e1e1e1;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #e1e1e1;

}
button { position: relative; background: #4fd577; } 
button:after { right: 100%; border: solid transparent; content: " "; height: 0; width: 0; position: absolute; pointer-events: none; } 
button:after { border-color: rgba(79, 213, 119, 0); border-right-color: #4fd577; border-width: 7px; top: 50%; margin-top: -7px; }
```

Use this tool to create css arrows :- http://cssarrowplease.com/

Comment: Why the two button:after blocks? Could they be combined?

Answer (score 1):

Inside your form create a division containing a division with the word SEARCH and an img with a unique class.

Position your out division to absolute, top minus the height of your textbox.
Float your Search division to the right, float, your img to the left.
Asign your search division a width and height.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/5BwLC/22/

HTML

```
  <div class="searchy">
   <div class="searc">
      <input type="search" name="ttsearch" data-style="mini" data-theme="d" placeholder="Search here..." class="fdSearch" value=""/> 
      <div  class="search-button" onclick="f()">
          Search
       </div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
    .searchy{

 min-height: 60px;
 background-color: #555;
 color: #FFF;
 margin-left: -15px;
 margin-right: -15px;
    overflow:hidden;
 }

 .fdSearch{
float:left;
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 5px solid #E5E4E2;
 margin: 2px;
 margin-left: -15px;
 margin-right: -15px;
 min-height: 40px;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding: 20px;
margin-top: 15px;
width: 85%;


}
.searc
{
 width:85%; 
 overflow:hidden;

}

.search-button
{
    margin-top:15px;
    margin-left:-40px;
min-height:40px;  
 width:10%;
 background-color:purple;
  float:left;  
    padding:20px;
     vertical-align: middle;
     border-radius: 10px;
 border: 5px solid #E5E4E2;

}
```

Would you like the arrow too?

Comment: .searchy, .searc and .fdSearch? Why these class names?

Comment: I dont know.. They were created by Robert. I just tweaked them to get to the result.

Answer (score 1):

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gxXYC/

```
.searchy{
     position:relative;
     height: 60px;
     width:480px;
     background-color: #555;
     color: #FFF;
 }
 .searchy:before, .searchy:after{
     position:absolute;
    top:0;
 }
.searchy:before{
    content:"";
   width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 10px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 10px solid transparent; 
    border-right:10px solid blue;
    right:100px;
    top:20px;
}
.searchy:after{
    content: "search";
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
width: 96px;
height: 84%;
top: 5px;
    font-size: 23px;
line-height: 44px;
background: blue;
right: 4px;
border-top-right-radius: 4px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
  }
 .fdSearch{
 background-color: white;
 border-radius: 10px;
 border: 5px solid #E5E4E2;
 height: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding: 20px;
 width: 100%;
 float:left;
}
```

the markup

```
<div class="searchy">
    <input type="search" name="ttsearch" data-style="mini" data-theme="d" placeholder="Search here..." class="fdSearch" value=""/> 
  </div>
```

if you want to use a submit button the git it an absolute position right width the same dimenssion as :after and an opacity :0;

http://jsfiddle.net/gxXYC/2/

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why I'm adding my answer to the heaps, but [here it is](http://jsfiddle.net/4zxgn/):

HTML:

```html
<div class="searchy">
    <div class="search-wrap">
        <input type="search" name="ttsearch" data-style="mini" data-theme="d" placeholder="Search here..." class="fdSearch" value="" />
        <button type="submit">Search</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```css
.searchy {
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #555;
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0 6%;
}
.searchy:after {
    content:'';
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.search-wrap {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: 5px solid #E5E4E2;
    margin: 2px;
    height: 40px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 85%;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}
.search-wrap > input, .search-wrap > button {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
    border: 0;
}
.search-wrap input[type="search"] {
    -webkit-appearance: textfield;
    -moz-appearance: textfield;
    appearance: textfield;
    width: 100%;
}
/* Unfortunately these have to be separate: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/style-placeholder-text/ */
 .search-wrap input[type="search"]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    font-style: italic;
}
.search-wrap input[type="search"]:-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 18- */
    font-style: italic;
}
.search-wrap input[type="search"]::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Firefox 19+ */
    font-style: italic;
}
.search-wrap input[type="search"]:-ms-input-placeholder {
    font-style: italic;
}
.search-wrap button[type="submit"] {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: #7c7aa9;
    color: #fff;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.search-wrap button[type="submit"]:before {
    position: absolute;
    content:'';
    border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #7c7aa9;
    height: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto 0;
    left: -10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no one 'right' answer to this. Here's how I would do it:

Make the purple box/arrow a background image of the input.

Put the search text/button in an absolutely positioned DIV positioned above the right side of the input box.